# Load Image from Flutter IOS plugin assets folder

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I try to write a plugin for my Flutter project, I want to load an image from plugin Assets folder, do anyone know how can I load this frame.png from objective c native code?

I tried use: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"frame" ofType:@"png"];

but it getting null. Anyone here know how to load this image?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: This question has NOT been answered IMO

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing a flutter plugin and need to have native assets these are the following things you have to do,

- Add your files in Assets folder or any other folder inside ios folder
- Add the following line in podspec file

> s.resources = 'Assets/*.png'

- Access the file using Bundle

> ```
> let bundle = Bundle(for: YourPlugin.self)
>
> let url = bundle.url(forResource: "frame", withExtension: "png")!
> ```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

after updating your podspec as suggested by Ayan, you can use your image like this

````
    ```let image = UIImage(named: "image.png",
                        in: Bundle(for: YourPlugin.self),
                        compatibleWith: nil)```
````